# Getting age of folders by the newest file inside

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint database which has been used for the last ~10 years and is an absolute mess. I am trying to find out which folders have not been used or updated for several years but can only seem to see when the folder was most recently updated.

Is there a way I can report the age of a folder by the last time any file within it was updated?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask, since you say it's been around for 10 years, but what version of SharePoint is this for?